# Retrieving and displaying data in Php from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve `firstName` from the member table in `z1760359` . When I execute the code , its only displaying the first name in the member table and the rest is not displayed

```
Member table in z1760359

select firstName from member

| Roberto   |
| Savannah  |
| Sai       |
| Adarsh    |
| Jane      |
```

---

```
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$pass='';  
$db="z1760359";
$db1=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$pass,$db) or die('Oops something     went wrong ');
$query= "SELECT firstName from member";
$message1=mysqli_query($db1,$query);
$message2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($message1);
foreach($message2 as $r1)
  {
     echo"$r1";

     echo"<br>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: when we use mysqli_fetch... & looping after it, the first result can't be shown. Use myqli_fetch.. in while loop to display the records...

Answer (score 3):

The code is storing only the last row to the variable. Try with -

```
while($message2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($message1)) {
    echo $message2['firstName'];
    echo"<br>";
}
```

Use 'while' loop Instead of using `foreach`.